# How to prove that this polynomial is greater than $0$ at a particular point?

Tags: calculus, inequality, polynomials, proof-writing

Given $$p(x)=x^3\left(1+\frac{b}{x}+\frac{c}{x^2}+\frac{d}{x^3}\right)$$ and $$t=1+3|b|+\sqrt{3|c|}+\sqrt[3]{3|d|}$$
where $b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$

How do I prove that $p(t)>0$?

I am trying to approach this problem by trying to solve this inequality: $$\frac{b}{t}+\frac{c}{t^2}+\frac{d}{t^3}>-1$$
However, this has gotten me nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$t \ge 1+ 3|b|$ implies that
$$
 \frac bt \ge -\frac{|b|}{t} \ge - \frac{|b|}{1+3|b|} > - \frac 13 \, .
$$
Similarly, $c/t^2 > -1/3$ and $d/t^3 > -1/3$. Then
$$
 1+\frac{b}{t}+\frac{c}{t^2}+\frac{d}{t^3} > 0
$$
and therefore $p(t) > 0$.